# POST fails on first submit, when I then hit back and submit again it works

Tags: ajax, node.js

This also doesn't happen to all users but what happens is:

1. Load page and click to open dialog box.
2. Enter email.
3. Click submit.
4. Get a "Cannot POST" error on the page.
5. Hit back.
6. Click submit again.
7. Post works.

The POST request:

```
var subscribeD = function(){
console.log("Subscribed function running");
var data = $('#subscribe-form2').serialize();
var emaildata = $('#subscribe-form2').serializeArray();
var email = '';
var download = "";
var downloadvalue = "";
var downloadvaluedesktop = "";
var linkvalue = "";
var linktestvalue = "";
var istakeawaylink = 'FALSE';
var subscribeissuccess = 'FALSE';

$('#subscribe-message2').html('Please wait...');
$("#subscribe-form2 :input").prop("disabled", true);
var i = 0;
while (i < emaildata.length){
    if (emaildata[i].name == 'email'){
        email = emaildata[i].value;
    }
    i++
}

var i = 0;
while (i < emaildata.length){
    if (emaildata[i].name == 'download-type'){
        download = emaildata[i].value;
    }
    i++
}
    var i = 0;
while (i < emaildata.length){
    if (emaildata[i].name == 'downloadvalue'){
        linktestvalue = emaildata[i].value.substring(0, 4);
        //console.log("linktestvalue = " + linktestvalue);
        //console.log("Passed from prismic = " + emaildata[i].value);
        if (linktestvalue == 'http'){
            linkvalue = emaildata[i].value;
            istakeawaylink = 'TRUE';
            console.log("Identified Link");
        } else {
            downloadvalue = '/assets/files/' + emaildata[i].value;
            downloadvaluedesktop = emaildata[i].value;
        }
    }
    i++
}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/subscribe",
        data: data, 
        success: function(data){
            $("#subscribe-form2 :input").prop("disabled", false);
            if(data.success){
                subscribeissuccess = 'TRUE';
                LoadUsersFile(download, istakeawaylink, linkvalue, downloadvalue, downloadvaluedesktop);
                console.log("Subscribe is Success");

            }   else {
                $('#subscribe-message2').html('Error occurred during subscribe. Please try again later.');
                console.log("Else Error Message Triggered");
            }
        }, error: function(){
            console.log("Error Triggered");
            $("#subscribe-form2 :input").prop("disabled", false);
            $('#subscribe-message2').html('Error occurred during during subscribe. Please try again later.');
        }
});
}
```

The Server Side:

```
module.exports = function(req, res){
var emailId = req.body.email;
var button = req.body.subscribe;
var api = require('../api');

var apikey = "removed";
var listid = "removed";

var body = JSON.stringify({apikey: apikey, id: listid, email: {'email': emailId}, merge_vars:{groupings:[{name:"MERGE1", groups:[button]}]}, double_optin: false, send_welcome: false}),
link = "/2.0/lists/subscribe.json";

api.call(link, body, function(data){
    try{
        var ret = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        if(ret.leid && ret.euid) res.json({success: true});
        else if(ret.code && ret.code == 214) res.json({success: true});
        else res.json({success: false});
    } catch(e){
        res.json({success: false});
    }       
}, function(err){
    res.json({success: false});
});
};
```

The code at ".../api"

```
module.exports = {
call: function (endpoint, body, callback, errcallback){
    var http = require('https');
    var options = {
        host: 'us5.api.mailchimp.com',
        post: 443,
        path: endpoint,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body),
            accept: '*/*'
        },
        method: 'POST'};

    var req = http.request(options, function(res){
        console.log('STATUS:' + res.statusCode);
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var data = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk){
            data = data + chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function(){
            callback(data);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
        errcallback(e);
    });
    req.write(body);
    req.end();
}
};
```

The HTML Form:

```
<form id="subscribe-form2" method="post" action="#">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="hidden" name="subscribe" value="left-button">
                        <input type="hidden" name="download-type" value="article-takeaway">
                        <input type="hidden" name="downloadvalue" value="<%- takeawaydownloadfilename %>">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail Address">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <input type="button" value="download" id="subscribe-button2">
                <div class="row" id="subscribe-message2" style="border-bottom: 0px !important; padding: 2px 15px; margin-top: 10px;font-size: 16px;">
                </div>
```

The Event Trigger:

```
$('#subscribe-button2').on("click", function(){
    subscribeD();
});
```

Logs from the browser: (shows The error messages when the post fails for the first time):

```
how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide:368 
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:3000/cleanblog/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide#:1 POST http://localhost:3000/practical-insights/how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide 404 (Not Found)
2Navigated to http://localhost:3000/practical-insights/how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide
jquery.main.js:943 Calling CSSStyleSheet.insertRule() with one argument is deprecated. Please pass the index argument as well: insertRule(x, 0).
addCSSRule @ jquery.main.js:943
(anonymous) @ jquery.main.js:976
j @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
ready @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
J @ jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: http://localhost:3000/cleanblog/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide:368
```

Logs from the server:

```
GET /practical-insights/how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide 304 347ms
GET /cleanblog/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 0ms
GET /cleanblog/css/clean-blog.min.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/css/mediaelementplayer.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/css/mejs-skins.css 304 0ms
GET /assets/css/all.css 304 2ms
GET /assets/css/social-sharing.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/css/fancybox.css 304 2ms
GET /assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js 304 1ms
GET /assets/js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js 304 1ms
GET /assets/js/jquery.sticky.js 304 0ms
GET /assets/js/jquery.main.js 304 1ms
GET /assets/js/mixpanel_scroll_tracker.min.js 304 1ms
GET /assets/images/bg-submit.png 304 1ms
GET /assets/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png 304 1ms
GET /assets/images/favicon/favicon-96x96.png 304 1ms
GET /assets/images/fancybox/fancybox.png 304 282ms
GET /cleanblog/css/bootstrap.min.css 304 2ms
GET /cleanblog/css/clean-blog.min.css 304 0ms
GET /assets/css/mediaelementplayer.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/css/mejs-skins.css 304 5ms
GET /assets/css/all.css 304 3ms
GET /assets/css/social-sharing.css 304 1ms
GET /assets/css/fancybox.css 304 1ms
GET /cleanblog/css/bootstrap.min.css.map 304 275ms
POST /practical-insights/how-to-achieve-goals-any-time-the-skeptics-guide 404 2ms - 81b
GET /cleanblog/css/bootstrap.min.css.map 304 740ms
GET /assets/images/favicon/favicon-16x16.png 304 4ms
GET /assets/images/favicon/favicon-96x96.png 304 2ms
GET /assets/images/fancybox/fancybox.png 304 336ms
STATUS:200
HEADERS: {"server":"openresty","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","content-length":"64","vary":"Accept-Encoding","date":"Sun, 08 Jan 2017 22:08:35 GMT","connection":"close","set-cookie":["_AVESTA_ENVIRONMENT=prod; path=/"]}
{"email":"ght@gmail.com","euid":"b330aa8ce1","leid":"118430401"}
POST /subscribe 200 308ms - 16b
```

The app.js file:

```
/**
* Module dependencies.
*/
var express = require('express'),
    favicon = require('static-favicon'),
    logger = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = require('method-override'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    cookieSession = require('cookie-session'),
    errorHandler = require('errorhandler'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    prismic = require('./modules/prismic-helpers'),
     api = require('./modules/api'),
     redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session),
     flash = require('connect-flash'),
     passport = require('passport');
    //bson = require('bson');

var app = express();
var moment = require('moment');

if (process.env.REDISTOGO_URL) {
    var rtg = require("url").parse(process.env.REDISTOGO_URL);
    var store = new redisStore({
        host : rtg.hostname,
        port : rtg.port,
        pass : rtg.auth.split(":")[1]
    });
} else {
    var store = new redisStore();
}



// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3100);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'assets', 'images', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());

//app.use(bodyParser());
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }))
//testing updated bodyparser info


app.use(methodOverride());
//app.use(express.session({ secret: secretKey, store: store, cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 86400000 }, maxAge: 360*5}));
app.use(cookieSession({ secret: "d!30dapdif3", store: store, cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 86400000 }, maxAge: 86400000}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(flash());
app.use(errorHandler());

//deals with the issue of blog/ redirecting to some weird page
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   if(req.url.substr(-1) == '/' && req.url.length > 1)
       res.redirect(301, req.url.slice(0, -1));
   else
       next();
});

var strategy = require('./modules/strategy')(passport);

//removed other routes for brevity
app.post("/subscribe", require('./modules/controller/subscribe'));

var PORT = app.get('port');

/*app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + PORT)
});*/


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('impaktlabs.com listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Where's the relevant server code......?

Comment: what is `data`? How do you define/initialize/assign it?

Comment: please put some more code here with html,and server side code

Comment: Sorry! Just added all the relevant code

Comment: Please also list any error messages showing up in your browser's console, as well as the status code of the corresponding network requests (both available in the developer tools of your favorite browser). And all related logs from your server.

Comment: @jcaron just added the error message I'm getting. Its a 404 and there are no errors on the server side. Again, I then hit back on the browser and resubmit the form and it goes through.

Comment: Logs are not limited to error messages. Also, you didn't provide the code that binds the requests to your handler.

Comment: @jcaron there isn't much in the logs but added the other text for both server and browser side. Is there something else I should be logging? I also added the code for the handler.  I'm updating a site that was created by someone else so don't have full knowledge, hence not providing all the info up front. Let me know if there is anything else I should add.

Comment: What happens if you add `return false;` after the call to `subscribeD` in your event handler?

Comment: @jcaron Still getting the same error with "return false;" added.

Answer (score 0):

After more trial and error fixed the error.

The problem was that my event handler is linked to a click on the submit button and not to the form itself, so the "return false;" suggested by @jcaron, wasn't actually preventing the default submit actions of the form.

I added a new handler that is linked to the submit of the code:

```
$("#subscribe-form2").submit(function(e){
        subscribeD();
        return false;
});
```

This fixed the issue.