# Html Form Posting Values to Django Backend only when submitted twice, or rather hit back to form and then submit again

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

So I have stumbled upon a case where my form does not post values after I click the submit button once, it goes to the next page indeed but my Django View can not fetch the post values.

But soon after I hit back button on browser and then clicks the submit button again it works ; I can then see the POSTed values in my DJango Views.

Here's my  HTML form. (Please note I have removed the unnecessary code which is long)

```
  <form action="" method="POST" id="quizform">

      {% csrf_token %}

     <fieldset class="cfield" id="box1">
     
        <p id="question" class="fs-title"> 1. {{data.0.question}}</p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="{% if data.0.correct_answer2 == "" %}col-12{% else %}col-9{% endif %}">
        <div class="form-check">
          
            <label class="form-check-label"> <img id="a1-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="answer_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
             
              <input id="a1{{data.pk}}" style="z-index: -1;" type="radio" class="radiobox form-check-input radio-box ans" name="q{{data.0.pk}}" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}" value="{{data.0.a1}}" required {% if data.0.correct_answer2  != "" %}disabled{% endif %}>
              <span class="cspan" style="color: white;">TES</span>
            </label>
            <span id="a1" class="cspan">{% if data.0.a1_image.url != None %}<img  src="{{ data.0.a1_image.url }}" class="" width="100px">{% endif %} {{data.0.a1}} </span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
           
            <label class="form-check-label"><img id="a2-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="answer_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
              <input id="a2{{data.pk}}" style="z-index: -1;"  type="radio" class="radiobox form-check-input radio-box ans" name="q{{data.0.pk}}" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}" value="{{data.0.a2}}" required {% if data.0.correct_answer2  != "" %}disabled{% endif %}>
              <span class="cspan"  style="color: white;">TES</span>
            </label>
              <span id="a1" class="cspan">{% if data.0.a2_image.url != None %}<img  src="{{ data.0.a2_image.url }}" class="" width="100px">{% endif %} {{data.0.a2}} </span>
            </div>
          <div class="form-check">
           
            <label class="form-check-label"><img id="a3-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="answer_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
              <input id="a3{{data.pk}}" style="z-index: -1;"  type="radio" class="radiobox form-check-input radio-box ans" name="q{{data.0.pk}}" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}"  value="{{data.0.a3}}" required {% if data.0.correct_answer2  != "" %}disabled{% endif %}>
              <span class="cspan"  style="color: white;">TES</span>
            </label>
              <span id="a1" class="cspan">{% if data.0.a3_image.url != None %}<img src="{{ data.0.a3_image.url }}" class="" width="100px">{% endif %} {{data.0.a3}} </span>
            </div>
          <div class="form-check">
           
            <label class="form-check-label"><img id="a4-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="answer_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
              <input id="a4{{data.pk}}" style="z-index: -1;"  type="radio" class="radiobox form-check-input radio-box ans" name="q{{data.0.pk}}" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}" value="{{data.0.a4}}" required {% if data.0.correct_answer2  != "" %}disabled{% endif %}>
              <span class="cspan"  style="color: white;">TES</span>
            </label>
              <span id="a1" class="cspan">{% if data.0.a4_image.url != None %}<img src="{{ data.0.a4_image.url }}" class="" width="100px">{% endif %} {{data.0.a4}} </span>
            </div>
            {% if data.0.a5 != "" %}
            <div class="form-check">
           
              <label class="form-check-label"><img id="a5-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="answer_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
                <input id="a5{{data.pk}}" style="z-index: -1;"  type="radio" class="radiobox form-check-input radio-box ans" name="q{{data.0.pk}}" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}" value="{{data.0.a5}}" required {% if data.0.correct_answer2  != "" %}disabled{% endif %}>
                <span class="cspan"  style="color: white;">TES</span>
              </label>
                <span id="a5" class="cspan">{% if data.0.a5_image.url != None %}<img src="{{ data.0.a5_image.url }}" class="" width="100px">{% endif %} {{data.0.a5}} </span>
              </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% if data.0.correct_answer2 != "" %}
        <div class="col-3">
          <br>
          <div class="form-group">
            <img id="c1-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="select_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
            <select name="correct_answer1{{data.0.pk}}" id="correct_answer1{{data.0.pk}}" class="form-control">
              <option>select</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a1}}" data-ans-no="a1">{{data.0.a1}}</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a2}}" data-ans-no="a2">{{data.0.a2}}</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a3}}" data-ans-no="a3">{{data.0.a3}}</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a4}}" data-ans-no="a4">{{data.0.a4}}</option>
              {% if data.0.a5 != "" %}
                <option value="{{data.0.a5}}"  data-ans-no="a4">{{data.0.a5}}</option>
              {% endif %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <img id="c2-icon-{{data.0.pk}}" src="/static/assets/img/correct.png" class="select_icon" width="20px" style="z-index: 99;" hidden>
            <select name="correct_answer2{{data.0.pk}}" id="correct_answer2{{data.0.pk}}" data-ans-no="asd" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}" class="form-control">
              <option>select</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a1}}" data-ans-no="a1">{{data.0.a1}}</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a2}}" data-ans-no="a2">{{data.0.a2}}</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a3}}" data-ans-no="a3">{{data.0.a3}}</option>
              <option value="{{data.0.a4}}" data-ans-no="a4">{{data.0.a4}}</option>
              {% if data.a5 != "" %}
                <option value="{{data.0.a5}}"  data-ans-no="a4">{{data.0.a5}}</option>
              {% endif %}
            </select>
          </div>
          <input class="btn btn-success multipleans" qid="{{ data.0.pk }}" type="button" value="submit">
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
    </fieldset>


               <button type="button" title="answer this question to enable the button" name="next" class="mybtn" id="nextpage" disabled> Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>

       <button type="submit" name="" class="mybtn" id="submitbtn" > Submit</button>


  </form>
```

Below is the Javascript :

```
<script>

var x={{datalength}};
$('#submitbtn').hide()
var y=1;
$('#nextpage').click(()=>{
  $('#nextpage').prop('disabled',true);
  $('#nextpage').prop('title',"answer this question to enable the button");
    var next;
    if(x !=y){
      next=y+1;
    $(`#box${y}`).hide()
    $(`#box${next}`).show()
    if(y<x){
        ++y;
    }
}
 if(y==x){
     $('#nextpage').hide();
     $('#submitbtn').show();
 }
})
$('#previspage').click(()=>{
    $('#submitbtn').hide();
    $('#nextpage').show();
    var pre=y-1;
    
    // $('#nextpage').hide();
    // alert(x)
if(pre<=0){
    
    return false;
}
else{
    $(`#box${pre}`).show()
    $(`#box${y}`).hide()
    if(y>pre){
        --y;
    }
}
 
})

</script>

<script>
 // Answer submit handler
$('.ans').change(function (e) {
  var $choice = $(this);
  var qid = $choice.attr('qid');
  var choice = $choice.val();
  var next_btn = document.getElementById('nextpage');



  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/check-answer/' + qid + '/',
    success: function (data) {
      $('input[qid=' + qid + ']').each(function (index, obj) {
        var image = document.getElementById("a"+(index+1)+"-icon-"+qid)
        $(obj).prop('disabled', true);
        if ($(obj).val() === data.correct && $(obj).val()) {
          if($(obj).val() == choice){
          image.src = '/static/assets/img/correctcolored.png';
          }else{
            image.src = '/static/assets/img/correct.png';
          }
          image.hidden = false;
        } else {
          if($(obj).val() == choice){
            image.src = '/static/assets/img/wrongcolored.png';
          }else{
            image.src = '/static/assets/img/wrong.png';
          }
          
          image.hidden = false;
        }
      });
      $('#nextpage').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#nextpage').prop('title',"");


    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
});
$('.multipleans').click(function (e) {
  var $submit = $(this);
  var qid = $submit.attr('qid');
  var $answer1 = document.getElementById("correct_answer1"+qid);
  var $answer2 = document.getElementById("correct_answer2"+qid);
  
  console.log($answer1.value)
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/check-answer/' + qid + '/',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data.correct2)
      var image1 = document.getElementById("c1-icon-"+qid)
      var image2 = document.getElementById("c2-icon-"+qid)
      if ($answer1.value === data.correct || $answer1.value === data.correct2){
        image1.src = '/static/assets/img/correctcolored.png';
      }else{
        console.log("test")
        image1.src = '/static/assets/img/wrongcolored.png';
      }
      image1.hidden = false;
      if (($answer2.value === data.correct || $answer2.value === data.correct2) && $answer1.value != $answer2.value ){
        image2.src = '/static/assets/img/correctcolored.png';
      }else{
        image2.src = '/static/assets/img/wrongcolored.png';
      }
      image2.hidden = false;
      $('#nextpage').prop('disabled',false);
      $('#nextpage').prop('title',"");
      $('input[qid=' + qid + ']').each(function (index, obj) {
        var image = document.getElementById("a"+(index+1)+"-icon-"+qid)
          $(obj).prop('disabled', true);
        if ($(obj).val() === data.correct || $(obj).val() === data.correct2) {
          image.src = '/static/assets/img/correct.png';
          image.hidden = false;
        } else {
          image.src = '/static/assets/img/wrong.png';
          image.hidden = false;
        }
      });


    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
});



</script>
```

I don't think the view has any problem as it is fetching the value correctly only after second form submit.

I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509882/post-fails-on-first-submit-when-i-then-hit-back-and-submit-again-it-works) , which is quite relevant problem, but I don't think I have any conflicting event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging I thought of a solution which worked.

Firstly I created a copy of the form.

```
var userSubmissionForm = document.getElementById('quizform');
```

Then I added the form input elements to this copy.

```
  const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenField.setAttribute('name', "q"+qid);
  hiddenField.setAttribute('value', choice);
  userSubmissionForm.appendChild(hiddenField);
```

Lastly I submitted the newform upon clicking the submit button.

```
  userSubmissionForm.submit();
```

**But I am still unsure why the first submit did not work.**